# Samsung X5 external SSD not recgonized

Tags: mojave, ssd, external-disk

I'm having trouble getting macOS Mojave to recognize a Samsung X5 external SSD.

When I plug the drive in, it lights up, but the OS doesn't seem to see it. I've plugged the drive into a Windows PC with a Thunderbolt 3 connector and Windows saw the drive fine, so it isn't a hardware issue.

Samsung has some encryption software preinstalled on the drive, so I disabled that via Windows hoping it would allow the Mac to see the drive, but no dice. I've installed the latest version of Samsung's software but that also doesn't seem to do anything.

I'm at a loss, any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Define "see the drive".  It doesn't mount, it doesn’t appear in Disk Utility, it doesn't appear in System Information... what?

Comment: I'd try the 3rd party app Mountain.  https://appgineers.de/mountain/. The app allows a free trial.  This app lists all volumes connected to a Mac and you can mount or unmount the volumes. It puts an icon in the menu bar. Clicking this displays the volumes.

Comment: @MarcWilson it doesn't show up anywhere, not in disk utility, not in System Information, can't mount what I can't see. I tried mountain as jmh recommended, no dice. It's like the drive isn't plugged in, but it lights up and other thunderbolt devices work in the same port.